# Environment Variable PHPRC got ignored

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with php5 version 5.5.9 and starting php via spawn-fcgi.

In the fcgi starter script I added an environment variable PHPRC and exporting this variable.

```
export PHPRC=/var/www/fcgi/user/php5
#...
exec /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -s $SOCKET -M 0660 -P $PIDFILE -C $CHILDREN -u $USER -g $GROUP -- /usr/bin/php5-cgi "$@"
```

But the php.ini from /etc/php5/cgi got loaded: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/cgi`

Even if the environment variable is set `Environment [...] PHPRC /var/www/fcgi/user/php5`.

Any Ideas what I'm missing? In my opinion this worked "yesterday"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for permissions. If the user don't have access to one of each parent directories it won't work. Even if there is no error message...